# Overlapping pools resource allocation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm for efficient allocation of resources from overlapping pools.

A simple example:

```
Pool 1 offers 100 resource points and allows participation for clients A, B , C
Pool 2 offers 300 resource points and allows participation for clients A, B 
Pool 3 offers 800 resource points and allows participation for clients B, C
```

Each client has specific needs , say client A needs 50 resource points, client B 400 and client C needs 200.
We need to figure out what how to efficiently use available pools to satisfy maximum number of clients.

Sounds like a candidate for some kind of iterative solution but I can't quite find an algorithm that would solve this problem - any ideas ?

Thanks